# Parallel running of functions

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, parallelism

I have 3 functions, like

```
function WatchDog {
sleep 1

#something
}
function TempControl {
sleep 480

#somthing
}
function GPUcontrol {
sleep 480

#somethimg
}
```

And i am runing it like

```
WatchDog | TempControl | GPUcontrol
```

This script is in *rc.local* file.
So, logically it should run at automatically.
The thing is that first function is doing fine. But second and third is not starting. 
But if I am starting it like

```
sudo bash /etc/rc.local
```

that is working fine. 
What is the problem? 
The same thing if i am adding it to init.d directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe sends the output of one command to the next.  You are looking for the `&` (ampersand).  This forks processes and runs them in the background.  So if you ran:

```
WatchDog & TempControl & GPUcontrol
```

It should run all three simultaneously.

Also when you run `sudo bash /etc/rc.local` I believe that is running them in series not in parallel (it waits for each command to finish before starting the next).  That would be sort of like this:

```
WatchDog ; TempControl ; GPUcontrol
```

**Command Separators**

> **;** semi-colon - `command1 ; command2`

This will execute `command2` after `command1` is finished, regardless of whether or not it was successful

> **&** ampersand - `command1 & command2`

This will execute `command1` in a subshell and execute `command2` at the same time.

> **||** OR logical operator - `command1 || command2`

This will execute `command1` and then execute `command2` **ONLY** if `command1` failed

> **&&** AND logical operator - `command1 && command2`

This will execute `command1` and then execute `command2` **ONLY** if `command1` succeeded.

Comment: So the "&" waitng them to finish, and ";" runing them immediately? Cos thats the endless loops, so they should start in one time.

Comment: I've edited my question with more detail about command separators.

Answer (score 10):

Simply with GNU **parallel**:

```
export -f WatchDog && export -f TempControl && export -f GPUcontrol

parallel -j3 ::: WatchDog TempControl GPUcontrol
```

---

- `export -f <funcname>` - export the function to be referred by `parallel`
- `-j N` - run up to ***N*** jobs in parallel

---

Test case for demonstration:

```
function a () { seq -s' ' 1 10; sleep 10; }
function b () { echo {a..z}; sleep 5; }
function c () { echo {-100..-80}; sleep 10; }
export -f a && export -f b && export -f c
parallel --no-notice  -j3 ::: c b a

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
-100 -99 -98 -97 -96 -95 -94 -93 -92 -91 -90 -89 -88 -87 -86 -85 -84 -83 -82 -81 -80
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```